# Roblox games take forever to open

Tags: technical-issues, roblox

When I try to open a game nothing happens for like 5 minutes. Then it says connecting to Roblox for like 3 more minutes, after which it opens the game.

I don't have any internet or performance problems. I have a pretty good PC and I have been playing Roblox for more than 3 years now.
This problem started happening one week ago. I tried everything I could to fix it, inclucing:

- Uninstalled Roblox 4 times
- Updating my internet drivers but they are already up-to-date
- Restarted my PC
- Opening it in another browser

But nothing made a difference.

Comment: Was this for all games, or were you trying to open the same game each time?

Answer (score 0):

- Disable Extensions and Add-Ons
- Open your task manager and close any unnecessary programs running in the background.
- Check if there are Browser Related Issues
  ▪ *The best browsers to play Roblox are Opera GX, Google Chrome, Firefox and Safari.*
- Make sure your Antivirus or Firewall is not blocking your access to the games
  ▪ [Find out if this is happening](https://www.windowsdispatch.com/check-windows-firewall-blocking-ports-programs/) then ***Temporarily*** *disable them and re-enable them when you are done playing the games for the day.*
- Uninstall unused programs
- Delete temporary files
- [Or is Upgrading to an SSD your solution?](https://www.reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/pswcvc/should_i_upgrade_hdd_for_ssd_or_upgrade_ram/)
- Stop unnecessary startups
- Run a disk clean-up
  ▪ [But please do it with caution and not before understanding the pros and cons.](https://www.minitool.com/data-recovery/what-is-safe-to-delete-in-disk-cleanup.html)
- Keep Ports Open
  ▪ *The port range that Roblox uses is UDP 49152 – 65535. Be sure to keep these ports open so that Roblox can connect to your

Comment: Partially plagiarized from https://gamertweak.com/fix-roblox-not-loading-games/

Comment: if it works it works.  giving a link as an answer isn't allowed here and rewriting doesn't really make sense either, but it would be good to give credit.

Comment: Most of the things listed here would prevent Roblox from starting at all if they were broken, but they would not just slow it down.

Answer (score 0):

Last year I had this issue too. Try:

- Reinstalling
- There might be an update
- Your computer is too old to support graphics or other functions